# Php: problem with associative arrays

Tags: php

If i have an array with hundreds of random ids (having values too) like

```
(3=>23,2=>34,17=>670,5=>67...)
```

how can i get an output like following via a loop

```
ID: 3 has a value= 23
ID: 2 has a value= 34
ID: 17 has a value= 670
ID: 5 has a value= 67
```

I can reference the values by their IDs like

```
  echo $myArray['3'];
```

but what if don't know in advance that what the next ID is? I mean how can i reference the IDs automatically with a loop? Is it even possible to code the following pseudo code in php?

```
myArray's first location's ID has value = $myArray[$myArray's first location item]
myArray's 2nd location's ID has value = $myArray[$myArray's 2nd location item]
```

Need help plz...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($myArray as $key => $value)
{
    echo "ID: $key has value of $value\n";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not just:

```
foreach ($myArray as $k => $v) {
  echo "ID: $k has a value= $v\n";
}
```

?

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach ($myArray as $key => $value) {
  echo "id: $key value: $value\n";
}
```